# HTTPoison manually close connection

Tags: elixir, httpoison

This is a very simple module that keeps checking the requester's IP. I use backconnect proxies which means that it gets new IP on every http request.

```
defmodule Test do
  def go() do
    Enum.each(1..1, fn x ->
    Task.Supervisor.async_nolink(Scraper.TaskSupervisor, fn ->
      r = HTTPoison.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", [],
        [timeout: 10_000, recv_timeout: 10_000, proxy: "ip:port", ssl: [{:versions, [:'tlsv1.2']}]])

      case r do

        {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
          IO.inspect body |> Jason.decode
          :timer.sleep(1000)
          go()
      end
    end)
    end)

  end
end
Test.go()
:timer.sleep(2000000)
```

Problem? HTTPoison(hackney) doesn't release the connection as long as process is alive so IP is always the same.
How would I manually close the connection inside:

```
{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
          IO.inspect body |> Jason.decode
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `HTTPoison` README:

> Normally **hackney** [opens and closes connections on demand](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#reuse-a-connection), but it also creates a [default pool](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#use-the-default-pool) of connections which are reused for requests to the same host. If the connection and host support keepalive, the connection is kept open until explicitly closed.

`HTTPoison` does not export the `close` for the underlying socket, and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/256) for that since 2017.

Meanwhile, you might call `hackney_pool:stop_pool(:default)`. This is obviously not the optimal solution by any mean and it has a huge overhead. So my advise would be to either provide a pull request to `HTTPoison` enabling close connection functionality (via delegating to [`;hackney_response.close/1`](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/652ccf1c493b4e2345a8bd1f13b60d39b6cc0a1b/src/hackney_response.erl#L346)) *or* simply get rid of redundant `HTTPoison` and just use `hackney`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution turned out bo be setting `pool: false`, the entire request looks like:

```
HTTPoison.get(url, [], [
  timeout: 5_000,
  recv_timeout: 5_000,
  proxy: proxy,
  hackney: [pool: false],
  ssl: [{:versions, [:'tlsv1.2']}]
])
```

Comment: That way you basically make your code single-threaded, which is not what most people expect from erlang.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin can you please explain? I spawn a bunch of unlinked processes, each executing the code above and sending results back. Not sure if this is proper multi-threaded execution but it works.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin disabling the pool doesn't mean it's single-threaded, it'll still create separate connections, it just doesn't keep them around.